# Method named getTime is not declared when using a Timestamp in Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

If I declare a user defined java expression (which uses janino) in Kettle like so:

```
new java.util.Date(agent_start_time.getTime())
```

(Where `agent_start_time` is defined as a Timestamp)

I get this error:

```
2015/07/23 16:25:10 - [test-timestamp].User Defined Java Expression.0 - Caused by: org.codehaus.janino.CompileException: Line 1, Column 44: A method named "getTime" is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype, nor through a static import
```

Which is strange as the doco states clearly that Timestamps support `getTime` just like `java.util.Dates` do (Albeit at a different granularity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the User-Defined Java Expression step doesn't support Timestamp parameters ([bug PDI-14347](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-14347)).

You can cast it to a Date, via a Select Values step, which appears to resolve the issue in my testing.

Comment: Hi, I tried to cast it into Date but failed and get this error `Line 1, Column 36: Unknown variable or type "agent_start_time"`